# Excel Microsoft 365: COUNTIF in odd rows only

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I have a column (B2:B70) in which I want to count the number of times a particular string ("RPA") occurs. However, I only want to consider the odd rows in my column (so basically, the range is B3,B5,B7 and so on). How can I do this, please? I'm working with Excel for Office 365.

I have tried:
COUNT IF
MOD
IF.
SUBTOTAL.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a different way to do it in Office365 but you could use SUMPRODUCT in any version.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B70="RPA"),MOD(ROW(B2:B70),2))
```

Comment: Excel 2010 onwards? Sumproduct was available a lot earlier than that. I'm pretty certain that it was in v1, if not even in the Excel precursor, Multiplan. You see the mention of XL 2010 in the MS documentation because that is the oldest version they still consider worthy of mentioning in their release history.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B$2:$B$5*(MOD(ROW($B$2:$B$5),2)=0)*1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`SUMPRODUCT()` will give you desired result. You can also use `FILTERXML()` like-

```
=SUM(--(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",FALSE,B2:B10)&"</s></t>","//s[position() mod 2 = 0]")="RPA"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could filter to odd rows that also contain RPA and then count the result:

```
=COUNTA(FILTER(B2:B70,(MOD(ROW(B2:B70),2)=1)*(B2:B70="RPA")))
```